# How can I select all people who frequent only the pizzerias that serve at least one pizza that person eats using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the name of every person who frequents only the pizzerias that serve at least one of the pizzas that person eats.

Here is the database schema:

```
create table person(
name                        varchar(20) not null primary key, 
age                         smallint default 20 not null, 
sex                     char default 'H' not null
);

create table frequent(
    name                        varchar(20) not null, 
    pizzeria            varchar(30) not null, 
    
    primary key(name, pizzeria),
    foreign key(name) references person(name)
);

create table eat(
    name
                            varchar(20) not null, 
    pizza               varchar(60) not null, 
    
    primary key(name, pizza),
    foreign key(name) references person(name)
);

create table serve(
    pizzeria            varchar(30) not null, 
    pizza               varchar(60) not null, 
    price                       decimal(10, 2) not null,
    
    
    primary key(pizzeria, pizza)
);

commit;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT M.NAME FROM 
EAT M WHERE M.PIZZA IN(
 SELECT S.PIZZA FROM 
 FREQUENT F JOIN SERVE S ON F.PIZZERIA = S.PIZZERIA WHERE 
 M.PIZZA = S.PIZZA  
)

Comment: Please don't post updates to your question in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64232441/edit) it instead. Also, please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using. You tagged this question both MySQL and PostgreSQL. Please specify one or the other.

Comment: Why would they frequent a pizzeria that doesn’t serve a pizza they eat? It seems half the tables here aren’t needed.

Comment: Using a name as a primary key is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @Bohemian they visit the pezzeria that at least it serve one pizza they eat

Comment: And your serve table has no pk

Comment: @Strawberry my teacher who did this

Comment: @Yasser_1D I'm asking why would someone go to a pizza shop that doesn't sell a pizza they like. They wouldn't. They would only go to pizzerias that sold pizzas they like. So `select * from person` is the answer.

Comment: @Bohemian its not like this ,they visit a pizzeria that serve at least one , they don't visit the pizzeria that doesn't serve what they eat i think you didn't understand me

Comment: @Yasser_1D I understand exactly what you mean, and you have expressed that perfectly in your most recent comment. So every person only frequents pizzerias that serve a pizza they like, so "every person" is the answer to your question as stted in the title.

Comment: @Bohemian  thank you , i think its me who didn't understand the query,sorry :)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select distinct x.name 
  from ... as x
  join ...
    on ... = ...
```